# Filter multidimensional array of dates to exclude weekends (saturdays and sundays)

Tags: php, arrays, date, filtering, weekday

I'm looping through an array of days in the current month to generate another array of days that are on or after the current day and this is working well. I now need to exclude/omit any dates if they are a Saturday or a Sunday.

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to include a check for Saturday/Sunday dates, something like:

```
date('N', strtotime($day)) >= 6);
```

with my existing code that generates an array:

```
// Get days for current month
    $day = date("Y-m-d");
    $i = strtotime($day);
    
    array("year" => array("month" => array(days)));
    $allDays = array(
        date('Y', $i) => array(
            date('n') => range(date('d', $i), intval(date('t'))),
        ),
    );
```

Not sure how to combine the test for a weekend date with this or whether I need to use a for loop etc here?

Comment: `$i = time()` would save you a lot of wasted cpu cycles with your current "get system time, mangle into string, then mangle string back into time". And yes, you'd need a loop because "range" isn't intended to "make a range but skip X,Y,Z values".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get all the days excluding weekends for the **current month**: you could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback to get the weekend days and then use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to create a new array containing only week days:

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('n');

$weekend_days = array_filter($allDays[$year][$month], function($d) {
    return (date('N', strtotime(date("Y-m-$d"))) >= 6);
});

$allDays[$year][$month] = array_diff($allDays[$year][$month], $weekend_days);

print_r($allDays);
```

Comment: The site no longer exists. The demo had the same code as the answer though.

Comment: You're welcome, Kalmesh!

Comment: With due respect, it's "Amal" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check on the date before adding each value to the array:

```
if (!in_array(date('w', $i), array('0', '6')))
{
    // add $i to array
}
```

Comment: Where is he adding anything to an array? Also, `$i` contains a timestamp.

Comment: @AmalMurali $i should contain a timestamp to be used in the date function. I'm assuming he is adding something to an array based on the description 'generate another array of days that are on or after the current day'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering the populated multidimensional array, perhaps you'd like to populate the desired array from the start.

Declare a datetime object for the first day of the current month.
Cache the month value for future reference.
Wind back the date by one day to reach the last day of the previous month.
Use the phrase "next weekday" to advance the object to only the next desired day.
Push the qualifying dates into your result array in the desired format.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8pPiX))

```
$result = [];
$dt = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$month = $dt->format('n');
$dt->modify('-1 day');
while ($dt->modify('next weekday') && $dt->format('n') == $month) {
    $result[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('n')][] = $dt->format('d');
}
var_export($result);
```

---

As an extension of this implementation, a multi-year array can be populated in a similar fashion.

The result is an array with year values as the first level keys, month values as second level keys, and **weekdays** as the third level values.

```
$result = [];
foreach ([2023, 2024] as $year) {
    $dt = new DateTime("$year-01-01 -1 day");
    while ($dt->modify('next weekday') && $dt->format('Y') == $year) {
        $result[$year][$dt->format('n')][] = $dt->format('d');
    }
}
var_export($result);
```